Get last part of the path with IFS_OBJECT_STATISTICS?
Path to multiple files is like this in the IFS (file system)
/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/File1.jpg
I want with sql in DB2 get the IBM IFS path like this sense Folder3 has all the folders I want.
Folder4/File1.jpg
I have tested with this sql code in DB2
 SELECT CAST(PATH_NAME AS CHAR(100))
  FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_OBJECT_STATISTICS(START_PATH_NAME => '/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3'))
 WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = '*STMF'
  ORDER BY PATH_NAME ;

But the result I get is
/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/File1.jpg
How can I change my query to list the lowest folder and the file in that folder. I don't want to have Folder1/Folder2/Folder3 in my result.
I don't get any error.

Learn about REGEXP_SUBSTR if it is available in your i-series Db2-engine. Google for examples.

I was dealing with a similar issue. My resolution is a little clunky, but works in my case and should for yours.
SUBSTRING(PATH_NAME, 32, 7)

Since my file path remains the same, I just substringed the path_name in the SQL.
